# Why is my alert(1) running in case 1 but not in case 2?

Tags: javascript, xss

I'm polishing my XSS skills, but one thing I don't get is why in case 2 my injection is not executing when I'm in fact escaping from the functioning and starting my own code. This code I got from W3Schools so is not anything malicious.

The question is: Why doesn't case 2 works and how would you change it for it to work.

Thank you.

Update: The injection in case 2 starts after: x="Good day";}...
so I cannot add a closing comments at the end of the script. I'm just curious as to why isn't the alert(1) working in the second case, is the browser not parsing that js because it is missing */  at the end? or because the injection didn't properly escaped from that function.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_ifthen

Case 1:

```
function myFunction()
{
    var x="";
    var time=new Date().getHours();
    if (time<20)
    {
       x="Good day";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
}

alert(1); //My injection
```

Case 2:

```
function myFunction()
{
    var x="";
    var time=new Date().getHours();
    if (time<20)
    {
        x="Good day";
    }
    var i =0;} alert(1);/*My injection is in this line
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
}
```

Comment: [Things to know about w3schools.](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: Also, what are "injection skills"?

Comment: In what way does it not work? What are you expecting it to do? What does it do differently from that?

Comment: After formatting the code, we can all see what the issue is

Comment: @Pointy: Unfortunately, I only have one upvote. Down with the fools! Such a shame there isn't a similar site for Code Academy.

Comment: Why the "xss" tag? Is this question about cross-site scripting? Is that what you mean by "injection"?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard no idea, I edited the question so it's better formated and removed the extra tag, but it looks like Op has reverted it

Comment: Also, XSS skills are not really something to polish... at least, not around here. Sort of frowned upon.

Comment: @Huangism: Obviously keen to point out his l33t injection skills.

Comment: Although looking at that javascript, I don't think the internet has anything to worry about.

Comment: **What are you doing?**  Clearly explain your definitions of _"XSS skills"_ and _"injection"_.  FWIW, you rarely see Allman style formatting applied to JavaScript.

Comment: @Sparky Thanks to everybody who tried to help/undestand the problem, after playing around with it for some time the way the injection works is by  instead of trying to comment out the rest of the code just enclosed it  within brackets so that the syntax works.   So I replaced: var i =0;} alert(1);/*   with:  var i =0;} alert(1);{   and got it to pop.

Comment: That didn't even come close to answering my simple question.

Answer (score 3):

You had an unterminated comment

```
function myFunction() {
    var x="";
    var time=new Date().getHours();
    if (time<20)
    {
        x="Good day";
    }
    var i =0;
} 

alert(1);  /*My injection is in this line document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x; }*/
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2xeYP/

Comment: Yes now that I look at it you're clearly right :) However the error may have been that extra `}`; the comment may have been added just for the question here.

Comment: The unformatted code was confusing

Comment: @Pointy yes very true, either way need more practice at injection skills

Comment: The missing closing multiline comment is intentional because in this injection exercise you only have control of input after: "x="Good day";
    } *injection goes here* document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x; }

Comment: @Zero What injection exercise?  How are you "injecting" code directly into this script?  Either you're leaving out a lot of detail or you don't understand how injection attacks work.

Comment: @zero please update the question if there are other key parts that could be causing the issue

Comment: @Huangism updated. Thanks a lot for taking a look at this.

Comment: @Zero with the current code you provided, the only issue is the fact that your comment is not closed. As you can see in the fiddle, the alert works with the comment closed